# How can I evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty }\left( x^2 - \frac x2 - (x^3 + x+1 ) \ln \left(1+ \frac 1x \right) \right)$ using L'Hospital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I find the following limit **using** the L'Hospital's rule?

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\left( x^2 - \frac x2 - (x^3 + x+1 ) \ln \left(1+ \frac 1x \right) \right)$$

---

I have already tried to replace $1/x$ with $t \,\,(t\rightarrow 0)$, but the only result I get is infinity, which is incorrect.

Comment: Can you write down in your post with details what you got after replacing $1/x$ with $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Taylor expansion, we see that for $x>1$,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{x^{3}}-\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{1}{x^{4}}\leq\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\leq \dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{1}{x^{3}},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}x+\dfrac{1}{3}+1+p\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\leq(x^{3}+x+1)\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\leq x^{2}-\dfrac{1}{2}x+\dfrac{1}{3}+1+q\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right),
\end{align*}
where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials.

By Squeeze Theorem, the limit goes to $-4/3$.

**With L'Hospital:**
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x^{2}-\dfrac{x}{2}+(x^{3}+x+1)\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{2x^{2}}+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{x^{3}}\right)\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{x^{3}}}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{t-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot t^{2}+(1+t^{2}+t^{3})\log(1+t)}{t^{3}}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1-t-(2t+3t^{2})\log(1+t)-(1+t^{2}+t^{3})\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+t}}{3t^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1-t^{2}-(3t^{3}+5t^{2}+2t)\log(1+t)-(1+t^{2}+t^{3})}{3(t^{3}+t^{2})}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-2t-t^{2}-(3t^{2}+5t+2)\log(1+t)}{3(t^{2}+t)}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{-2-2t-(6t+5)\log(1+t)-\dfrac{3t^{2}+5t+2}{1+t}}{3(2t+1)}\\
&=-\dfrac{4}{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor series you get $\log(1+1/x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^3}+\ldots$, thus $$(x^3+x+1)\log(1+1/x)=(x^3+x+1)(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^3}+\ldots)=$$
$$x^2-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+1+\text{other terms that goes to 0 for }x\rightarrow\infty.$$
Hence 
$$\lim x^2-\frac{x}{2}-(x^3+x+1)\log(1+1/x)=\lim x^2-\frac{x}{2}-[x^2-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+1+\ldots]=-4/3.$$

Comment: Using Taylor series, everything goes alright, but I need to get the same answer with L'Hospital's :<

Comment: @MariaWhite, you may look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove by L'Hospital that

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+\frac1{3x^3}\right)}{-\frac1{4x^4}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac1{x^5+x^4}}{\frac1{x^5}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^5}{x^5+x^4}=1 \\\iff \ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)=\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+\frac1{3x^3}+O\left(\frac1{x^4}\right)$$

therefore

$$x^2-\frac12 x-(x^3+x+1)\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)=$$

$$=x^2-\frac12 x-(x^3+x+1)\left(\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+\frac1{3x^3}+O\left(\frac1{x^4}\right)\right)=$$

$$=x^2-\frac12 x--x^2+\frac12x-\frac13-1+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)=-\frac43+O\left(\frac1{x}\right) \to -\frac43$$

Comment: What is O? And do you differentiate something?

Comment: This is the Big-O notation, it simply means that we have other negligeble terms equal or smaller than $1/x^4$. Thus is the more efficient way to use L’Hospital in this case (see the first limit). Note also that we don’t need to guess the approximation for the log but we can obtain it using l’Hospital.